# What is preserved between playthroughs of Void Bastards?

Tags: void-bastards

If I were to start a new game in *Void Bastards*, would I keep any progress (constructed items, parts, materials) from the previous game?

Does creating a new game overwrite previous progress?

Answer (score 1):

Starting a new game overwrites previous progress. There is no way to save multiple games in progress, and nothing carries over when you start a new game. (I can't find any documentation of this online, but it is what happened when I started a new game.)